# SQL Server stored procedure to empty specific tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which is supposed to truncate specific tables based on their names.

Tables which do not have "A" as the first character in their names must be truncated.

The problem is that this code doesn't work! Please help

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[return_data]
  @DBName varchar(100)
AS

declare @i int, @tc int
set @i = 1

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(100)
SET @sql = 'USE ' + QUOTENAME(@DBName) + '

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.tables
'
EXECUTE(@sql)

OPEN cur

declare @tbl_name nvarchar(100)
declare @first_char char(1)

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @tbl_name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

    set @first_char = SUBSTRING(@tbl_name, 0, 1)

    set @sql = 'DELETE FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@tbl_name)
    if (@first_char != 'A')
    begin
      EXECUTE(@sql)
    end

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @tbl_name
END

CLOSE cur    
DEALLOCATE cur

return
```

Comment: What is happening? Errors or nothing?

Comment: Nothing happens when the code is executed! I think the problem is in my IF statement.

Comment: While Dan is correct about the problem and how to fix, you should run this to see why: `SELECT SUBSTRING('test', 0 , 1)`. It returns an empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the SUBSTRING function.  The starting position is a 1-based ordinal, not 0-based. Try

`SUBSTRING(@tbl_name, 1, 1)`

or

`LEFT(@tbl_name, 1)`

Also, I suggest you make it a habit of schema-qualifying table names to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: And wouldn't hurt to move the `set @sql = 'DELETE` to inside the `if (@first_char` block.